# Different results with WP_Query() and query_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running WordPress 3.8.1 and I'm having difficulties getting a correct result using WP_Query().
I'm using an array with these arguments:

```
$args = array(
  'tag_slug__and' => array('usa', 'china'),
  'category__and' => array(211, 420),
  'posts_per_page' => '-1',
  's' => 'money',
);
```

The following code works just as I want it:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = new WP_Query();
return $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query($args);
```

Whereas this gives me an empty result:

```
$obj = new WP_Query();
$posts = $obj->query($args);
return $posts;
```

I var_dumped each object and they look exactly the same, except for one difference - the first code has a "posts" key with the result whereas the second code has an empty "posts" key. (I found no differences in the SQL)

The first code above is taken straight out of query_posts().

I should add that the "s" key in the arguments affects the result. If I remove the row that contains the search string ("s" key), the second code works as well.

Do I have to use $GLOBALS to get this to work with "s"?

Comment: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

Comment: Thank you! I never tried get_posts() and it did exactly what I wanted!